# how the same spinner looks different in different device

Tags: android

Hi I have created a spinner using the following code. I didn't set any background image. I am getting good look and feel in Motorolla Milestone but some rubbush look and feel in Samsung Galaxy Ace!

```
<Spinner
                    android:layout_width="160dip"
                    android:layout_height="40dip"
                    android:id="@+id/spnContactTypes" />
```

See the different outputs of same spinner

[image]

Comment: I think the ace has a normal pixel density while the milestone has a high density screen. If that's the case android might be clipping spinner (which it looks like it's the case). Have you tested your app in any other screen with normal density in HVGA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resources in Android can differ between Devices, Manufacturers, Service Providers, Android Versions, etc.

So the Galaxy Ace uses some different resources than Milestone.

If you want exactly the same visuals on all devices you have to create them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The way that the widget looks, is influenced by the theme that is currently used on the device or within the application.

If you don't have a custom theme for your app, the widget will use the device theme and there will be noticeable differences.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

A similar post regarding themes:

[Android changing colors with themes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014152/android-changing-colors-with-themes)