# android spinner material drop down behavior

Tags: android, spinner, dropdown

How can I create a spinner,which drop down behavior would like 
[here](https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0B3321sZLoP_HTS1LdnhrTl9TRzg/components-buttons-otherbuttons-060203_MobileDropdowns_xhdpi_006.webm)

Thank you.

I'm interested in how to make its dropdown behavior like on video. When we click spinner it is not drop down below the view. Its dropdown view appears around selected item.

Comment: its view actually depends upon your device version

Comment: @Pavan did you mean **android version**?

Comment: yes in android version you just implement Spinner and check . check with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666826/how-the-same-spinner-looks-different-in-different-device

Comment: show what code  you implemented and how it looking on your device

Answer (score 0):

[**Check documentation**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) for spinner it is explained very well

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Apply the adapter to the spinner
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```