# How can i change the spinner's style? android

Tags: android, styles, spinner

I need to change the spinner's style because if i place the spinner in my app, the spinner is invisible but if you click on it you will get the drop down part...
can someone please help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3014713/967142

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably set a wrong android:width or android:height. In any case, please show the xml and the java.

Best regards.