# Changing Android styles by using theme

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, android-attributes

I have an app with a few different `Activities`. The different activities have different styled buttons, texts, etc... I've set up all the components to have various styles based on their location/Activity. (Eg. `style="@style/MainMenuActionBarTitle`, or `style="@style/MainMenuActionBarTagLine`). These styles set the `background` (`Drawable`, `MipMap`, or `Color`), `textColor`, etc...

The app will be offering some theme packs which change the colors of these various components throughout the application, and I was hoping there was a way to have `Styles` with the same name, but different values based on the `Theme` of the app. This way I can just change the `Theme` whenever the `Activity` is loaded to whatever Theme the user has chosen.

There's some good info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014152/android-changing-colors-with-themes) on how to change the standard widget look & feel using Themes, but that changes the look and feel for the standard-un-styled widgets.

Is there a way to accomplish this using Themes, or is this the wrong direction altogether? Is there a better/easier route?

**Edit:** After doing more research and more fiddling, I've realized what I  want to do isn't far off from how I can accomplish this. What I want to do is to actually change component `Styles` when I set the `Theme` of the `Activity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution I've discovered is to use `attributes` which the `Theme` can point to different `Styles`.

attrs.xml

```
<resources>
   <!-- Attributes referencing whatever style the theme needs to set up. -->
   <attr name="main_menu_button_style_play" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

themes.xml

```
<resources>
   <!-- Base application theme. -->
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
       <!-- App specific attributes -->
       <item name="@attr/main_menu_button_style_play">@style/MainMenu.Button.Play</item>
   </style>

   <!-- Blue application theme. -->
   <style name="AppTheme.Blue" parent="AppTheme">
      <!-- App specific attributes -->
      <item name="@attr/main_menu_button_style_play">@style/MainMenu.Button.Play.Blue</item>
   </style>
</resources>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="MainMenu.Button.Play">
    <item name="android:background">#f76d3c</item>
    <item name="android:text">PLAY</item>
</style>

<style name="MainMenu.Button.Play.Blue">
    <item name="android:background">#2ca8c2</item>
</style>
```

activity.xml

```
<Button android:id="@+id/main_play_button"
        style="?attr/main_menu_button_style_play"/>
```

This works really well, and allows me to set the `Theme` in the `Activity.onCreate()` method.

The only annoying problem I have with this solution is that Android Studio complains that the `Button` is missing the `layout_width` and `layout_height` even though they're defined in the `Style`. I guess it doesn't follow the attribute reference back through the chosen `Theme`.

Another approach which is what I ended up using was to more heavily use the attributes. Creating attributes for all the properties values I want to change between themes. So, instead of `main_menu_button_style_play` which defines the style reference, I used `main_menu_button_play_background`. This approach is the same amount of work as simply specifying a style because themes can inherit, but the IDE understands it.