# Do mobile apps have the capacity to be completely customizable by users?

Tags: android, ios

Similar to a web page, can a person using a mobile app have the ability to change colors, fonts, etc?
Let me make use a lolable analogy and example:

[You see how this subsite is customized by the user it's for](https://www.gaiaonline.com/profiles/the-admin/13374222/)?

[And how this subsite is different and customized by its user too](https://www.gaiaonline.com/profiles/npc-gaia-staff/37422851/)?

[Now look at this dramatically different and also super duper nice subsite customized by its user](https://www.gaiaonline.com/profiles/puppercrust/28817739/)!

[Here's a bot with their default subsite for contrast's sake](https://www.gaiaonline.com/profiles/firstrankseoservices/43663611/).

Does a mobile app have the same customizable abilities on the user end? Could a hypothetical user download an app and add images, change fonts, manipulate the placement of user info viewable to other users, etc?

Comment: Short answer is it depends. It depends on the platform and the customization which is exposed by the developer. For a native apps you cannot do much beyond that. If developer thinks an app shouldn't be customized, then you cant do much about that. Same for the web apps also. Reason is users dont have access to the source server files. Also note that your problem is overly broad. You should only request more specific questions from this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend doing some google searches, and searches here on stack overflow.

Yes, it's just as possible with mobile apps as it is with websites, but it's not necessarily as easy as giving the user a text box to put html or other markup into (Although you could make the app render html).

You have to develop it into the app, just as you would if you were making a website (like the gaiaonline site).

You can see many other answers already here for how to do parts of what you're asking, and I will respond to any questions you have as comments on this answer as well.

Here is one simple example:
[Android changing colors with themes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014152/android-changing-colors-with-themes)

Comment: Thanks so much for that response and example! I have absolutely no development and programming experience, but I was just curious.

Comment: Ok, cool! I'm happy to answer any more questions you have, @Sch. If my existing answer is helpful, you're welcome to click the checkmark below the voting arrows to select it as the answer to your question. This should award you reputation points on stack overflow as well as me. Thanks!